# Get an unique identifier in Javascript of an image already loaded by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, hash, image

I have some pages that display book informations, and they use an **external** cover server to get the covers, putting the appropriate url in the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

The cover server does not have all the covers, so very often it returns me a default blank cover .

I need a way to know, javascript-side and once the page is loaded, if the cover returned by the cover server is the default blank image, in order to substitute that default blank image with custom html code. So I've tried to calculate an unique identificator for the cover image.

I thought to do this using canvas' `drawImage` method and then getting an hash of `canvas.toDataUrl`, but the latter returns me a Security Exception, since the image comes from an external server.

Do you have any better (and working) idea to achieve my goal?

Comment: Does the blank image have a unique url, or does the server just spit out a blank image at the same url as a cover should be at?

Comment: No, the url is of the kind http://www.coverserver.com/bookid, and if the server has no cover for that bookid, it returns the default blank cover

Comment: looks like you need some kind of rest api for asking your server if it has cover image or not..

Comment: I can't, since the cover server is not under my control.

Comment: so what exactly is the final end goal?

Comment: why not just base it off of the url for the default book cover?

Comment: to inderstand if, for example, the img with src=coverserver.com/1245 or the img with src=coverserver.com/3421 is the blank cover or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done at the client side. It would be a security hole (cross-site scripting) if it were possible for script from one domain to look at the contents of an image that came from another domain.

You would have to find the information either using a separate service on the third-party server, or by fetching the image at the server side and comparing it with the filler image. (Suggest using a HEAD request to check the length first and see if that matches the known length of the filler image, for speed.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do an XmlHttpRequest for the cover image, like a HEAD request, and then look at the ETag header value (or Content-MD5 or something).

Comment: My desire was to not do any further request, but, as @bobince observed, it seems to be impossible due to security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Are the width and height of the empty image different to normal images? If so, use that as a guide.